# How to enable openssl in libcurl without recompling PHP

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, openid

I'm trying to implement OpenID login in PHP by using php-openid library. But it did not work on my server probably because PHP libcurl is using NSS, not OpenSSL for SSL connection(according to phpinfo).

I could not find any reliable documentation to handle this situation.  My server is normal CentOS6 and PHP 5.3 is installed from yum.

Currently, php -i | grep SSL shows like this:

```
SSL => Yes
SSL Version => NSS/3.13.1.0
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

I think I need to make PHP's SSL version like this:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.0
```

Does anyone know how to enable OpenSSL without recompling PHP? 
Thanks a lot in advance for any information or advice, where to look.

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses libcurl which uses the SSL library. You don't need to rebuild PHP but you need to provide a separate libcurl that is built to use the SSL library of your choice.

Alas, you need to build libcurl to use OpenSSL or install a libcurl-OpenSSL and then have your PHP use that libcurl instead of the original one.